# Calculando Integral utilizando R

Tags: r, matemática

Estou precisando calcular essa simples integral abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Se trata da função quantil da normal padronizada, onde de ante mão sabemos que, `q_0.5(z) = 0`, por exemplo.

Ou seja, para cada theta (percentil) ela me da um numero na densidade normal padronizada. O theta vai de 0 a 1.

Eu gerei essa função no R e organizei em uma matriz:

```
thau=1:99/100
qnorm(thau,0,1)

matrix=matrix(0,99,2)
matrix[,1]=thau
matrix[,2]=qnorm(thau,0,1)

colnames(mattrix)=c("theta","q(z)")
```

Como calculo essa interal no R, dado que eu ja tenho a função q??

Eu pensei em calcular as duas integrais utilizando as regras básicas de integral. Posso fazer isso para essa função? Eu acho que posso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estaria correto? Para mim deu `-1.170456`.

Adoraria a ajuda de vocês.

Obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o que entendi sobre o teu problema, creio que ele não pode ser resolvido. Note que

[image: eq1]

Assim, a integral está indefinida entre 0 e 0,5. Ela diverge neste intervalo. Seria como integrar 1/x entre 0 e 1, por exemplo.

A tua conta chega num resultado porque ela não está correta. Generalizando o teu resultado, ele é equivalente a

[image: eq2]

Se supusermos que f(x)=1, segundo a tua fórmula, temos

[image: eq3]

Mas isto é uma indeterminação, pois temos 0/0. Portanto, não haveria solução para este problema. Mas basta ver que, se f(x)=1, temos

[image: eq4]

que é uma integral claramente bem definida no intervalo em que estamos interessados. Portanto, a derivação do teu resultado não é verdade e a tua resposta não é `-1.170456`. Inclusive, a tua integral é divergente e teu problema não tem solução.

Seria interessante voltar ao problema original e ver de onde esta integral surgiu para entender qual o motivo de calculá-la.

Comment: Obrigada, @MarcusNunes. Editei a equação, me equivoquei. Acho que esta um pouco confusa minha pergunta, vou melhorar. Mas basicamente a função ´q_theta(z)´, o numerador, é essa função: ´plot(qnorm(thau,0,1))´.  Eu quero calcular a integral do numerador de 0 até 0.5. A integral do denominador é que eu não consigo calcular.

Comment: Pois então. Não dá pra calcular a integral do denominador. Rode o comando `x <- seq(0, 0.5, 0.0001); plot(x, qnorm(x)/(qnorm(x)^2), type="l")` e veja como o valor desta função diverge. Como `qnorm(0.5)=0`, `(qnorm(0.5))^2=0`. Logo, o denominador é `0` em `0.5`. Portanto, a função `qnorm(x)/(qnorm(x)^2)` não está definida em 0,5, impedindo que sua integral seja calculada.

Comment: me surgiu uma dúvida. Vou aproveitar o tópico. Qual a função eu posso usar para calcular a integral dessa função que eu plotei plot(qnorm(thau,0,1)), ou de qualquer outra, sem precisar criar um function? Eu achei a função AUC: auc(thau[1:50],matrix[,2][1:50]). É a mais indicada?

Comment: Não conheço esta função auc, então não posso dizer exatamente para o que ela serve. Se eu tivesse que resolver o teu problema, eu criaria uma função trivial no R e calcularia a integral a partir dela, desta forma: `funcao <- function(x) return(qnorm(x)); integrate(funcao, lower=0, upper=0.5)` (se alguma das minhas respostas te ajudar, não esqueça de votar e aceitar como definitiva)